# Rails devise let user sign in on one rails app by checking the users credentials on a second rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, devise, activeresource

i have the problem that i have on rails app that stores all the user data and uses devise. What i'd like to do is create a second app lets the user sign in and sign out and are authenticated on the frist app. In the end i'd like my users on the the second app to be merely active resources and not be stored on the app itself. I've read a lot about overwritung the registriations controller and token authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved via [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) Maybe it will be useful for you: http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/.